# consolidating redundant information in loop

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

In Java, I have an array that contains a long series of sometimes redundant key value pairs that I want to consolidate into a shorter arraylist which only has unique keys.  How do I edit the code below to accomplish this?

Here is an example of the data in the `outputarr` array:

```
key value
448 Ethanol
448 Alcohol
448 Alcohol
448 Ethanol
448 Ethanol
448 Alcohol
448 Ethanol
448 Alcohol
448 Ethyl alcohol
```

I want to consolidate the above into an array with the following data:

```
key value
448 Ethanol; Alcohol; Ethyl alcohol
```

Thus, 9 rows in the array get consolidate into one row in the arraylist.  And the value in the arraylist is a concatenated string `"Ethanol; Alcohol; Ethyl alcohol"`.  But every numerical key will have a different number of values that will need to be concatenated in this way in order to produce a single value string listing the unique names that were associated with the numerical key in the array.

Here is the code I have so far, how do I edit it to make it accomplish what I have described?

```
private static ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> twoDimArrList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
public void someMethod(){
    int len = 1000;
    String[][] outputarr = new String[len][2];
    // ommitting code that populates outputarr because the next for loop is what needs help

    for(int r=0;r<len;r++){
        ArrayList<String> temp = new ArrayList<String>();
        if(outputarr[r][0]==outputarr[r+1][0]){
            if(outputarr[r][1].equalsIgnoreCase(outputarr[r+1][1])){
                temp.add(outputarr[r][0]);
                temp.add(outputarr[r][1]);
                twoDimArrList.add(temp);
                r+=1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have to use a 2d array? I would make an object, with an int called key and an arraylist called value. That way you have an arraylist of objects and if you match a key then add the value

Comment: If you can use guava, it has a HashMultiMap which does exactly that. Otherwise a `Map<Integer, Set<String>>` would work too.

Comment: You can just use a standard HashMap in java with a loop body that looks something like this:  if (map.get(key) == null) { map.put(key,value) } else { value = map.get(key) ; update value ;)

Comment: @assylias SetMultimap actually (second `m` is lowercase)

Comment: @j.con I have about 40 lines of code that I am omitting above, which process the string values to remove extraneous content and spelling/case errors.  If I can just plug that into your object approach, then I could do your object approach.  The result needs to be sent into a txt file, which is going to be imported into a database.  Can you show code?

Comment: @fge you meant HashMultimap, right? ;-)

Comment: @assylias well, yes, this would be the implementation to use in this case

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways you can do this. One way is to use a `Map<Integer,Set<String>>` to hold the data, this would map keys to sets of values.

Then, as you read your data:

```
Map<Integer,Set<String>> data = new HashMap<Integer,Set<String>>();

for each item in the file {

    Integer key = ...; // parsed 
    String value = ...; // parsed

    // retrieve set if it exists, create if it doesn't.
    Set<String> values = data.get(key);
    if (values == null) { 
        values = new HashSet<String>();
        data.put(key, values);
    }

    // add value to set
    values.add(value);

}
```

If you want to store duplicate values, use a `List` instead of a `Set`. If you want to e.g. count values, consider creating a new class that holds a value and its count (with appropriate implementations of `equals()`, `hashCode()`, and/or `Comparable`), and store a `Set` of those that you update as values are read.

You could conceive of any number of other approaches as well, but ultimately all would boil down to something like the above: Map an integer ID to a collection of values.

You can also simplify your code a bit if you use one of the [third-party multimaps](https://www.google.com/search?q=multimap%20java), which essentially implement the above, such as Guava or Apache Commons implementations; the JDK doesn't have any built-in multimaps, unfortunately ([see "Multimaps" section here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html)).

---

`HashMap` and `HashSet` don't guarantee any particular ordering when you iterate over the values in the container. If you have specific ordering requirements, a `TreeMap` / `TreeSet` will iterate in ascending order (natural order as defined by `Comparable` / `Comparator`), and a `LinkedHashMap` / `LinkedHashSet` will preserve the order that the elements were added in. The containers above can be substituted with these as needed.

As for iterating over the data, standard methods and syntax can be used, e.g.:

```
for (Map.Entry<Integer,Set<String>> entry : data.entrySet()) {
    Integer key = entry.getKey();
    // ...
    for (String value : entry.getValue()) {
       // ...
    }
}
```

The mistake you made in your current output-formatting attempt was to rely on `Set`s default `toString()` implementation to produce your output. The default `toString()` can't really guess your specific requirements, it's up to you to iterate over your data and produce output that satisfies your requirements.

Comment: Better to use Set instead of List

Comment: also, when performance will be important, be sure to not use boxed primitives... not possible with "standard" Java collections, but there are ways to overcome this.

Comment: @SargeBorsch In this case, the cost of reading and parsing the file, and manipulating maps/sets, will make the cost of boxing/unboxing negligible. Also recall `Integer.valueOf()` returns an already wrapped type, so that could help during load. Appropriate hash functions would make a much more significant impact on performance -- if performance requirements aren't actually being met in the first place. Implementing a high level algorithm that actually works is the first priority.

Comment: If you don't want to be at the mercy of `Map.toString()` (which you rarely do, the default string conversion has no way of guessing how you want your data formatted), you will have to manually iterate over each entry in the map (see `.entrySet()`), then manually iterate over each entry in the value set, and write your data out in the format you see fit. If you have specific ordering requirements, you can use different containers, e.g. a `TreeMap` / `TreeSet` will iterate in ascending order, a `LinkedHashMap` / `LinkedHashSet` will preserve insertion order. Your call.

Comment: @CodeMed I've added some details in my answer.

Comment: @CodeMed I'd shy away from that replaceAll()/substring() approach to output formatting. Java makes no guarantees that toString() will produce strings of any specific format, and that code could certainly break some day; although I suppose it's fine (but kludgy) for a short one-off project. The real way to do it is to iterate over keys and values (as in the iteration example above) and build and write output strings as you go.

Comment: @CodeMed My suggestion gives you precisely every single tool you need to solve that problem, and more, and only leaves out the most basic of string operations. It is expected that you are able to figure out how to `String x = ...; x += ...;` on your own. It is also presumed, based on your original question, that you are sufficiently advanced to understand the role of the default `toString()` in what you are doing. The blanks you need to fill in here are very basic, and we are not here to do your work for you, unfortunately.

Comment: @SargeBorsch Presumably, the OP was unsatisfied that nobody spoon-fed him the answer (hence unaccepting and changing upvote to downvote, *shrug*).

Comment: ... which is actually a little confusing given that @CodeMed 's other questions here indicate he's been a Java programmer for at least 3 years, and should *probably* know how to concatenate strings by now (or at least, should know how SO works).

Comment: this is so (facepalm)